# PL/Python3 with VARIADIC arrays as arguments

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, variadic-functions, stored-functions, plpython

I'm using `plpython3u` to process a result that contains an arbitrary number of columns each of which hold an array (of varying lengths > 0). In python, I'd be expecting to process this data as a multidimensional array but I'm having trouble getting it from Postgres into my function.

The function declaration I am using looks like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_set_cover_possible(VARIADIC args numeric[][])
```

The problem is that when I try

```sql
SELECT is_set_cover_possible(ARRAY[1,2],ARRAY[1,2]);
```

I get:

> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

If I pass in `(ARRAY[1,2])` the function returns a result without failing so it seems postgres can't handle the multidimensional declaration above.

So, if it's actually possible: **How do I declare the function so as to receive a *list* of arrays?**

Answer (score 2):

You cannot to do it. Arguments used as variadic arguments cannot be arrays.

Implementation of variadic arguments was at time when this was not possible technically. Now it is possible, but nobody implemented it.

Comment: Is it a good solution to overload the function with a large number of possible arguments (and handle the case of too many arguments separately)?

Comment: I don't see any benefit of this. I don't know your use case, but variadic parameters are little bit syntactic sugar - you can pass multidimensional array instead. The most simple solution is usually the best.

Comment: The advantage is mainly that I don't know how many parameters there will be. The query is constructed dynamically and the arrays vary in length (I haven't tested this but it seems that pg has issues with multidimensional arrays of different lengths).

Comment: you can use array of rows containing arrays